# PHP SoapClient write response to file

Tags: php, optimization, soap, xmlreader

It's the first time I'm using SOAP (but I'm pretty good in PHP). My problem is that I connect to a server that sends me large xmls through soap (large as in bigger than 50mb) and I don't know what PHP's SoapClient uses to parse xml but I'm afraid it might make my script run out of memory.

Could I write the SOAP response to file so I don't end up using too much memory? Or is that even a threat?

Normally I would write the response to file and then read it with XMLReader but right now I just get the response parsed.

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://....wsdl",array(
     'login' => 'test',
     'password' => 'test'));
 $something =  $client->__soapCall('getThings',array());
 var_dump($something);
 die();
```

Comment: how about trying to inherit the SoapClient and override those functions that receives the xml response from the server and then you could do everything you want, but I believe you should familiarize yourself with this object as well (all it's methods and how they work for the object).

Comment: @colighto And where do I find out more about the class? Maybe get its definition? I tried php.net but it wasn't very helpful

Comment: try this link it has the list of all the methods from this object http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php that you'll need, but anyway when it comes on soap webservice I'm using the Zend_Soap_Client object it comes with the package of Zend framework I believe it's much more cool and pretty easier to use and they do have a good documentation about it's uses. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that before you could write it on a separate file it's already occupying some space on your memory and the worse it would do a lot of process and occupy more space on the memory instead, I think another good approach is to look for a parameter on the function your using that could control the size of the response like for each response I want only to have a maximum of 5mb response size. I find it a bit difficult to explain but it's something you would do with pagination concepts you limit each page to 5 items for example on page 1 display 5 items, on page 2 another 5 items and so on. If that wouldn't work or it's not possible to do so then the last option is upgrade your server to be able to support what you really need I know this might be a heavier option but if there is no other way then I think this would be the most feasible option to resolve you problem. :)